# Search last 4digits and match the exact or nearest result in the database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, matching

I'm working in a project where i need to search for the last 4digit of a mobile number and display the exact match or if not suggest the nearest number to it.

Example: 
if user will search for 8773302 it match the 4digit from the database, it will display 8173302 (from database)

else if not found, it will display other suggestions like:
8173301, 8173303, 8173304, 8173305 and so forth.

CODE:

```
$existNo = "8673302";
$search = substr($existNo, -4);
$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);
echo $plan;

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
    $x++;
    if($x==1)
    $construct .="mobileno LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    else
    $construct .="AND mobileno LIKE '%$search_each%'";
}

$constructs ="SELECT * FROM mobilenum WHERE $construct OR status = '0'";
$run = mysql_query($constructs);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
{
    header ("LOCATION:suggestedNo.php");
}
else
{ 
    $getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobilenum WHERE $construct") or die (mysql_error());
    //Table Results 

    while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
    {
        $verifyMobileNo= $runrows ['mobileno'];
        $verifyMobileStat= $runrows ['status'];
    }

    $matchMobileNumber = $verifyMobileNo;
    if ($verifyMobileStat == "0"){
        header ("LOCATION:matchNo.php");
    }
    else {
        header ("LOCATION:suggestedNo.php");
    }
}
```

Hope somebody can help thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You should avoid using `mysql_*` functions, instead make use of `mysqli_*` or my personal preference `PDO` for your database functions as they are much more secure, `mysql_*` is not, especially seeing as you're not sanitizing any input.

Comment: This will not be particularly performant, but `WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(mobilenum FROM -4) AS UNSIGNED) >= search OR CAST(SUBSTRING(mobilenum FROM -4) AS UNSIGNED) < search ORDER BY ABS(search - CAST(SUBSTRING(mobilenum FROM -4) AS UNSIGNED)` should come close.

Comment: @Novocaine i'll take note of that, i'm still new in php mysql programming..

Comment: @Boldewyn would you mind to paste the where will i insert your code from my code. sorry newbie here. thanks in advance.

Comment: The complete (though untested) query: http://pastebin.com/0y8mMuT1

Comment: Thanks for the code @Boldewyn, but i cannot make it work. here is my sample code.

Comment: <?php
require_once ('../MySQLConnector/config.php');
$search = $_POST['search'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobilenum WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(mobileno FROM -4) AS UNSIGNED) >= `$search` OR CAST(SUBSTRING(mobileno FROM -4) AS UNSIGNED) < `$search` ORDER BY mobID(search - CAST(SUBSTRING(mobileno FROM -4)") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 
 
 echo "this is your new number".$row['mobileno']."<br>";
 
}
?>